# Apply multiple functions to each row of a dataframe

Tags: r, transform, rows, dataframe, apply

Every time I think I understand about working with vectors, what appears to be a simple problem turns my head inside out. Lot's of reading and trying different examples hasn't helped on this occasion. Please spoon feed me here...

I want to apply two custom functions to each row of a dataframe and add the results as a two new columns. Here is my sample code:

```
# Required packages:
library(plyr)

FindMFE <- function(x) {
    MFE <- max(x, na.rm = TRUE) 
    MFE <- ifelse(is.infinite(MFE ) | (MFE  < 0), 0, MFE)
    return(MFE)
}

FindMAE <- function(x) {
    MAE <- min(x, na.rm = TRUE) 
    MAE <- ifelse(is.infinite(MAE) | (MAE> 0), 0, MAE)
    return(MAE)
}

FindMAEandMFE <- function(x){
        # I know this next line is wrong...
    z <- apply(x, 1, FindMFE, FindMFE)
        return(z)
}

df1 <- data.frame(Bar1=c(1,2,3,-3,-2,-1),Bar2=c(3,1,3,-2,-3,-1))

df1 = transform(df1, 
    FindMAEandMFE(df1)  
)

#DF1 should end up with the following data...
#Bar1   Bar2    MFE MAE
#1      3       3   0
#2      1       2   0
#3      3       3   0
#-3     -2      0   -3
#-2     -3      0   -3
#-1     -1      0   -1
```

It would be great to get an answer using the plyr library and a more base like approach. Both will aid in my understanding. Of course, please point out where I'm going wrong if it's obvious. ;-)

Now back to the help files for me!

Edit: I would like a multivariate solution as column names may change and expand over time. It also allows re-use of the code in future.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are thinking too complex here. What is wrong with two separate `apply()` calls? There is however a far better way to do what you are doing here that involves no looping/apply calls. I'll deal with these separately, but the second solution is preferable as it is truly vectorised.

### Two apply calls version

First two separate apply calls using all-Base R functions:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Bar1=c(1,2,3,-3,-2,-1),Bar2=c(3,1,3,-2,-3,-1))
df1 <- transform(df1, MFE = apply(df1, 1, FindMFE), MAE = apply(df1, 1, FindMAE))
df1
```

Which gives:

```
> df1
  Bar1 Bar2 MFE MAE
1    1    3   3   0
2    2    1   2   0
3    3    3   3   0
4   -3   -2   0  -3
5   -2   -3   0  -3
6   -1   -1   0  -1
```

Ok, looping over the rows of `df1` twice is perhaps a little inefficient, but even for big problems you've spent more time already *thinking* about doing this cleverly in a single pass than you will save by doing that way.

### Using vectorised functions `pmax()` and `pmin()`

So a better way of doing this is to note the `pmax()` and `pmin()` functions and realise that they can do what each the `apply(df1, 1, FindFOO()` calls were doing. For example:

```
> (tmp <- with(df1, pmax(0, Bar1, Bar2, na.rm = TRUE)))
[1] 3 2 3 0 0 0
```

would be MFE from your Question. This is very simple to work with if you have two columns and they are `Bar1` and `Bar2` or the first 2 columns of `df1`, always. But it is not very general; what if you have multiple columns you want to compute this over etc? `pmax(df1[, 1:2], na.rm = TRUE)` won't do what we want:

```
> pmax(df1[, 1:2], na.rm = TRUE)
  Bar1 Bar2
1    1    3
2    2    1
3    3    3
4   -3   -2
5   -2   -3
6   -1   -1
```

The trick to getting a general solution using `pmax()` and `pmin()` is to use `do.call()` to arrange the calls to those two functions for us. Updating your functions to use this idea we have:

```
FindMFE2 <- function(x) {
   MFE <- do.call(pmax, c(as.list(x), 0, na.rm = TRUE))
   MFE[is.infinite(MFE)] <- 0
   MFE
}

FindMAE2 <- function(x) {
   MAE <- do.call(pmin, c(as.list(x), 0, na.rm = TRUE))
   MAE[is.infinite(MAE)] <- 0
   MAE
}
```

which give:

```
> transform(df1, MFE = FindMFE2(df1), MAE = FindMAE2(df1))
  Bar1 Bar2 MFE MAE
1    1    3   3   0
2    2    1   2   0
3    3    3   3   0
4   -3   -2   0  -3
5   -2   -3   0  -3
6   -1   -1   0  -1
```

and not an `apply()` in sight. If you want to do this in a single step, this is now much easier to wrap:

```
FindMAEandMFE2 <- function(x){
    cbind(MFE = FindMFE2(x), MAE = FindMAE2(x))
}
```

which can be used as:

```
> cbind(df1, FindMAEandMFE2(df1))
  Bar1 Bar2 MFE MAE
1    1    3   3   0
2    2    1   2   0
3    3    3   3   0
4   -3   -2   0  -3
5   -2   -3   0  -3
6   -1   -1   0  -1
```

Comment: @LookLeft - Regarding your edit, I'm fairly certain Gavin's vectorized `pmin`,`pmax` solution will handle a data frame with any number of columns, with any names. But I'm just guessing what you mean by 'multivariate' here.

Comment: +1 for great description. The looping issue and general solution using do.call were very insightful. I am starting to understand more about vectors and the way R functions treat them. I'll continue to play with each example.

Comment: @joran. Yes, the edit was in response to Gavin's comment and answer. He spotted the limitation and supplied a great answer.

Answer (score 19):

I show three alternative one-liners:

- Using the `each` function of `plyr`
- Using the `plyr` `each` function with base R
- Using the `pmin` and `pmax` functions that are vectorise

---

## Solution 1: plyr and each

The `plyr` package defines the `each` function that does what you want.  From `?each`: *Aggregate multiple functions into a single function.*  This means you can solve your problem using a one-liner:

```
library(plyr)
adply(df1, 1, each(MAE=function(x)max(x, 0), MFE=function(x)min(x, 0)))

  Bar1 Bar2 MAE MFE
1    1    3   3   0
2    2    1   2   0
3    3    3   3   0
4   -3   -2   0  -3
5   -2   -3   0  -3
6   -1   -1   0  -1
```

---

## Solution 2: each and base R

You can, of course, use `each` with base functions.  Here is how you can use it with `apply` - just note that you have to transpose the results before adding to your original data.frame.

```
library(plyr)
data.frame(df1, 
  t(apply(df1, 1, each(MAE=function(x)max(x, 0), MFE=function(x)min(x, 0)))))

  Bar1 Bar2 MAE MFE
1    1    3   3   0
2    2    1   2   0
3    3    3   3   0
4   -3   -2   0  -3
5   -2   -3   0  -3
6   -1   -1   0  -1
```

---

## Solution 3: using vectorised functions

Using vectorised functions `pmin` and `pmax`, you can use this one-liner:

```
transform(df1, MFE=pmax(0, Bar1, Bar2), MAE=pmin(0, Bar1, Bar2))

  Bar1 Bar2 MFE MAE
1    1    3   3   0
2    2    1   2   0
3    3    3   3   0
4   -3   -2   0  -3
5   -2   -3   0  -3
6   -1   -1   0  -1
```

Comment: Was just showing that. You get extra bonus point for the 0 in the pmin/max colls. I get extra bonus points for allowing any number of columns in `df1` :P

Comment: @GavinSimpson My revised answer shows three alternative (one-liner) ways of solving the problem, two of which allow any number of columns.

Comment: Now you are just showing off! ;-) Nice. Solutions 1 and 2 will be slow (dog slow on large problems) and we probably shouldn't be encouraging use of non-vectorised solutions over vectorised ones. But it isn't clear that the OP wants a generic solution to a multivariate apply or a solution to this specific problem. So I'll let the gratuitous **plyr** usage pass this once ;-)

Comment: I would like a multivariate solution. Wow, please excuse me while I digest all this amazing help and I'll get back to everyone ASAP.

Comment: +1 for completing the plyr() side of things. Bug thanks! I've tried all three and Gavin is spot on. Using my actual data (100c x 23000r) and a slightly more complicated process that loops through adding columns incrementally, the speed of each is: do.call(Gavin) is 29s, Solution 2 is 105 seconds and Solution 1...still waiting. So the plyr() library is not the best solution in this case. I shall continue testing.

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of good answers here.  I started this while Gavin Simpson was editing so we cover some similar ground.  What the parallel min and max do (pmin and pmax) is pretty much exactly what you're writing your functions for.  It may be a little opaque what the 0 does in pmax(0, Bar1, Bar2) but essentially 0 gets recycled so that's it's like doing

```
pmax(c(0,0,0,0,0,0), Bar1, Bar2)
```

That will take each item of the three things passed and find the max of them.  So, the max will be 0 if it was negative and accomplishes much of what your ifelse statement did.  You could rewrite so you get vectors and combine things with functions similar to what you were doing and that might make it a bit more transparent.  In this case we'd just pass the dataframe to a new parallel and fast findMFE function that will work with any numeric dataframe and get out a vector.

```
findMFE <- function(dataf){
    MFE <- do.call( pmax, c(dataf, 0, na.rm = TRUE))
}

MFE <- findMFE(df1)
```

What this function does is add an extra column of 0s to the passed data frame and then call pmax passing each separate column of df1 as if it were a list (dataframes are lists so this is easy).

Now, I note that you actually want to correct for Inf values in your data that aren't in your example... we could add an extra line to your function...

```
findMFE <- function(dataf){
    MFE <- do.call( pmax, c(dataf, 0, na.rm = TRUE))
    ifelse(is.infinite(MFE), 0, MFE)
}
```

Now, that's proper use of the ifelse() function on a vector.  I did it that way as an example for you but Gavin Simpson's use of MFE[is.infinite(MFE)] <- 0 is more efficient.  Note that this findMFE function isn't used in a loop, it's just passed the whole data frame.

The comparable findMAE is...

```
findMAE <- function(dataf){
    MAE <- do.call( pmin, c(dataf, 0, na.rm = TRUE))
    ifelse(is.infinite(MAE), 0, MAE)
}
```

and the combined function is simply...

```
findMFEandMAE <- function(dataf){
    MFE <- findMFE(dataf)
    MAE <- findMAE(dataf)
    return(data.frame(MFE, MAE))
}
```

MFEandMAE <- findMFEandMAE(df1)
df1 <- cbind(df1, MFEandMAE)

Some tips

If you've got a scalar if statement don't use ifelse(), use if() else.   It's much faster in scalar situations.  And, your functions are scalar and you're trying to vectorize them.  ifelse() is already vectorized and runs very fast when used that way but much slower than if() else when used scalar.

Also, if you're going to be putting stuff in a loop or apply statement put as little in there as possible.  For example, in your case the ifelse() really needed to be taken out of the loop and applied to the whole MFE result afterwards.

Comment: I accepted the challenge and provided a one-liner solution using `plyr` and *normal* `min` and `max` functions in my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks John. The description of the extra 0 column was useful and explaining the best use of ifelse() is still being digested; ie Loop Vs Whole. I hope one day to return the favours to everyone or "pass them forward".

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really want it, you can:

```
FindMAEandMFE <- function(x){
    t(apply(x, 1, function(currow){c(MAE=FindMAE(currow), MFE=FindMFE(currow))}))
}
```

(not tested - it should return an array with two (named, I think) columns and as many rows as the data.frame had). Now you can do:

```
df1<-cbind(df1, FindMAEandMFE(df1))
```

Very icky. Please heed Gavin's advice.

Comment: Thanks, I shall stick with Gavin's advice.